# How to host Frontend using Amplify CLI as part of CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, cicd, aws-amplify-cli

I have an existing Amplify project, which we are using only to host the frontend. I want this to be part of the CodePipeline I am creating such that, when there is a commit in the github repository, it triggers CodePipeline stages and in Code Build I should then be able to invoke Amplify to do the deployment in the existing frontend project. Below is the buildspec.yml using Amplify CLI commands.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
      - amplify configure --frontend --accessKeyId $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secretAccessKey $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --yes
      - amplify init --yes
      - amplify hosting add --force
  #    - amplify pull d1i5kk1oqc52po ----accessKeyId $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secretAccessKey $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --yes
  build:
    commands:
      - amplify publish
```

But I keep getting errors as Amplify CLI tries to look for inputs, I want this to run in a complete automated way without any inputs. For example:

```
 Cannot prompt for [Select the plugin module to execute] in a non-interactive shell
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done the above, so this is an educated guess.

You will only `init` the project to use Amplify once. And you will only add hosting once. Those commands make changes to the configuration of your project which you commit as part of the project's source code.

I'm not sure you even need the `amplify pull` as that will sync the local project with the cloud project; but any changes should have already been committed.

Have you tried simply not doing all the above and just `amplify publish`?

Unless someone chimes in with a better answer, I strongly recommend you just read the doc for Amplify Hosting.